# How can i add in a table and substract the same amount from another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tabeles:
stock with:

- productID
- quantity
- limit

and buyer with:

- name
- surname
- address
- desiredquantity
- productID

How can i set it so that when i add to desiredquantity from buyer it subtracts the same amount from  quantity in the stock table?

Comment: You write 2 queries, perhaps wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Think about this a little though; what happens if `quantity` has a number **lower** than `desiredquantity` Do you *really* want a negative value for `quantity`? There is much more to such things than simply "subtracting" the value. Checks need to be made, and integrity needs to be maintained. In the *real word* this is not as "simple" as subtracting *x* from *y*.

Comment: And what happens when you **delete** a row in buyer? You need to think about how a rows are added, modified, and deleted over time. Presumably you left out of your buyer table the productID column - something that will be needed for this logic.

Comment: So first I need to check if the desiredquantity is higher or equal to quantity and then substract, but I still don't know how to do that. Rows won't be deleted because it's only for a project so I just need it to run ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the check constraint by replacing the TABLENAME with actual table name

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME>
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_<TABLENAME> CHECK (Quantity>0 )
```

-- FOR CREATING THE TRIGGER, THIS SHOULD DRIVE THE CONCEPT, PLEASE MAKE APPROPRIATE CHANGES TO SUIT YOU REQUIREMENT.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_<TableName2>_Insert]
   ON [dbo].[item_detail]
   AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE <Table1>
        SET quantity = ISNULL(quantity,0) - ISNULL(inserted.desiredquantity,0)
        FROM
            inserted 
        WHERE 
            inserted.productid = <table1>.productid

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should add a check constraint on the quantity field on stock table so that it doesn't allow a value less than 0.

Then you can write a trigger on the buyer table which on insert into the buyer table would subtract the same quantity on the stock table.

Instead for such cases it is desired to use a ledger table which has every transaction of the stock coming in and going out and gets a record inserted into it with the type of transaction , '+' if inward '-' if outward and the stock can be a calculated field.

Comment: I have little to no ideea on how to do that, but I'll check it out and do the research. Thanks for the answer!